# How to find the last row in column A and print the timestamp by using google apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I want to print the timestamp in the last row of column A once I click a button so that I don't need to use the shortcut key `CTRL + SHIFT + ;` to generate the timestamp as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

This is my script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet ();
  var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction
  var aLast = ss.getRange("A"+(ss.getLastRow()+1)).getNextDataCell(direction.UP).getRow()
  var destRange = ss.getRange(aLast+1,1);

  destRange.setValue(dt)
}
```

I assigned the function to the button and run the script, but this is the error that show to me:

[image]

I'm still new to google apps script, may I know where did I did wrong in my script? Any advise will be appreciated!

Comment: I proposed a modified script by guessing your situation. Could you please confirm it? If my guess of your situation was not correct, I apologize for this. At that time, can you provide the detail information for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, I thought that the last row might be the same with the bottom row of the sheet. In this case, such error occurs. In your script, when the values of `ss.getLastRow()` and `ss.getMaxRows()` are the same, I think that the error occurs. If my understanding is correct, in order to avoid this, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const dt = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), 'Asia/Singapore', 'HH:mm:ss');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var direction = SpreadsheetApp.Direction

  // I modified below script.
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var destRange;
  if (lastRow == ss.getMaxRows()) {
    destRange = ss.getRange("A" + (lastRow + 1));
  } else {
    var aLast = ss.getRange("A" + (lastRow + 1)).getNextDataCell(direction.UP).getRow();
    destRange = ss.getRange(aLast + 1, 1);
  }
  destRange.setValue(dt);
}
```

#### References:

- [getMaxRows()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getmaxrows)
- [getLastRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getlastrow)

Comment: Hi Tanaike, yes you are correct! With your modified script, it works perfectly now. Thanks!

Comment: @weizer Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.